# cassandra unable to create table keyerror

Tags: cassandra, cqlengine

Im trying to create a table but get this error -

```
    keyspace = cluster.metadata.keyspaces[ks_name]
KeyError: 'cqlengine'
```

Models:

```
import uuid
from cqlengine import columns
from cqlengine.models import Model
from datetime import datetime
from cqlengine.management import sync_table


class Tickets(Model):
    ticket_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    created_dt = columns.DateTime(default=datetime.now())
    division = columns.Text()
    pg = columns.Text()
    duration = columns.Text()
    error_count = columns.Text()
    outage_caused = columns.Text()
    system_caused = columns.Text()
    addt_notes = columns.Text()
    ticket_num = columns.Text()
    ticket_type = columns.Text()
    row_create_ts = columns.DateTime(default=datetime.now())
    row_end_ts = columns.DateTime(
        default='9999-12-31 00:00:00.00000-00')


#connection.setup(['127.0.0.1'], "cqlengine", protocol_version=3)
# sync_table(Tickets)
from cqlengine import connection
connection.setup(["localhost"], "cqlengine")
sync_table(Tickets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you have not created a keyspace called `cqlengine`. You need to create a keyspace before using it.In this case you need to use cqlsh to create a keyspace called `cqlengine`, before running `sync_table`.